# Browse Button coming Differently in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, file, internet-explorer, input

Implemented Browse Button with the following input tag

```
<input type="file" name="test" style="padding-right: 5px; vertical-align: middle;"> </input>
```

This is working properly in `Firefox` and `Chrome` and coming as following way:

[image]

In `Internet Explorer` the same is coming differently as following:

[image]

How to Fix this different behavior of Browse Button ?

Comment: Browsers have their own default styles for elements. Saying Firefox and Chrome are working "properly" is not really accurate. There is no proper, just different. You can always target the input directly (`input[type="file"] { ... }`) and override the defaults to create a more uniform look across browsers.

Comment: [CSS2/DOM - Styling an input type="file"] for information point of view please visit this link:==>  http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: There's also [`::-ms-browse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn336890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) pseudo-element in IE. With that you can style some properties of `input type="file"`.

Comment: @Teemu : For this Minimum supported client - Windows 8 ?

Comment: @VaibhavJain Seems to work with Win7 and IE11 too. Though I couldn't find a styling whcih would switch the order of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Hi every browsers have its default styles for every elements. For this there is not exact solutions but you can use uniform.js to match same in every browsers only effected in file.

```
 $('input[type=file]').uniform();
```

Comment: is there any other alternative of uniform.js ? May be with CSS positioning or any other ?